# Actions/state to load data from backend

Tags: angular, ngxs

I've just started experimenting with `ngxs` but from my reading so far I'm not 100% clear on where I should be calling back to my API to persist and read data (all examples I've seen are either not doing it, or using some mock).

E.g. I've created a state where I maintain a list of items.  When I want to add an item, I dispatch the 'AddItem` action to the store, where I add that new item to the state.  This all works ok - the question is where is the appropriate place to plug in the call that POSTs the item to the server?

Should I call the API in my action implementation i.e. just before I update the store's item list.

Or should I call the API in my Angular component (via a service), then dispatch the 'Add Item' action when I received a response?

I'm quite new to this area, so any guidance or pros/cons of these approaches would be great.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best place is in your action handler.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { State, Action, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

//
// todo-list.actions.ts
//
export class AddTodo {
  static readonly type = '[TodoList] AddTodo';
  constructor(public todo: Todo) {}
}


//
// todo-list.state.ts
//
export interface Todo {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  complete: boolean;
}
​
export interface TodoListModel {
  todolist: Todo[];
}
​
@State<TodoListModel>({
  name: 'todolist',
  defaults: {
    todolist: []
  }
})
export class TodoListState {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
​
  @Action(AddTodo)
  feedAnimals(ctx: StateContext<TodoListModel>, action: AddTodo) {

    // ngxs will subscribe to the post observable for you if you return it from the action
    return this.http.post('/api/todo-list').pipe(

      // we use a tap here, since mutating the state is a side effect
      tap(newTodo) => {
        const state = ctx.getState();
        ctx.setState({
          ...state,
          todolist: [ ...state.todolist, newTodo ]
        });
      }),
      // if the post goes sideways we need to handle it
      catchError(error => window.alert('could not add todo')),
    );
  }
}
```

In the example above we don't have a explicit action for the return of the api, we mutate the state based on the `AddTodo` actions response.

If you want you can split it into three actions to be more explicit,

`AddTodo`, `AddTodoComplete` and `AddTodoFailure`

In which case you will need to dispatch new events from the http post.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I'll try your example here against my app.  
Similarly, I assume we'd define a 'LoadTodos' action, and have that action handler load the initial data from the server (as the default state will be empty). Does that sound correct?

Comment: You can use the NgxsOnInit lifecycle event to dispatch a LoadTodos action. and then add an action handler for that. It's in the documentation how you do that.

Comment: Got it - I see that now under the Advanced -> LifeCycle part of the documentation (admittedly I hadn't read everything under Advanced yet).
Thanks again for the help, really liking what I'm seeing so far with NGXS

Answer (score 4):

If you want to separate the effect from the store you could define a base state class:

```
@State<Customer>( {
    name: 'customer'
})
export class CustomerState {
    constructor() { }

    @Action(ChangeCustomerSuccess)
    changeCustomerSuccess({ getState, setState }: StateContext<Customer>, { payload }: ChangeCustomerSuccess ) {
        const state = getState();
       // Set the new state. No service logic here.
       setState( {
           ...state,
           firstname: payload.firstname, lastname: lastname.nachname
       });
    }
}
```

Then you would derive from that state and put your service logic in the derived class:

```
@State<Customer>({
    name: 'customer'
})
export class CustomerServiceState extends CustomerState {

    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private store: Store) {
        super();
    }

    @Action(ChangeCustomerAction)
    changeCustomerService({ getState, setState }: StateContext<Customer>, { payload }: ChangeCustomerAction) {

        // This action does not need to change the state, but it can, e.g. to set the loading flag.
        // It executes the (backend) effect and sends success / error to the store.

        this.store.dispatch( new ChangeCustomerSuccess( payload ));
    }
}
```

I have not seen this approach in any of the NGXS examples I looked through, but I was looking for a way to separate those two concerns - UI and backend.